# Symplectic isotopies between small balls?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a connected symplectic manifold, possibly with boundary.  Let $g_1, g_2: B(1) \to X$ be two balls in $X$.  Is it true that if $\delta$ is sufficiently small, then there is an ambient isotopy from $g_1|_{B(\delta)}$ to $g_2|_{B(\delta)}$?  To be clear, by this I mean a smooth family of symplectic maps $\Psi_t : X \to X$ such that $\Psi_0 = id$ and $\Psi_1(g_1) = g_0$.

If this is true, does anyone have a proof or a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: This is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61994/how-transitive-are-the-actions-of-symplectomorphism-groups .

Comment: According to "Introduction to Symplectic Topology" by McDuff and Salamon, it is not known. See Section "Blowing up and down". I don't know what was done after the book was written.

Comment: @Hwang Thanks for your response.  I don't have a copy of Introduction to Symplectic Topology, and I couldn't find a .pdf online, but are you sure that it is stated there that this question is not known?  Note that the question does not ask for a $\delta > 0$ such that any two $B(\delta)$ are isotopic, which is known to be not known; rather, the question asks about subballs of two fixed balls, which I think should be easier.

Comment: Now I have a problem in understanding your question. You pick two arbitrary balls of size 1 and take subballs of them. Is it different from picking arbitrary two balls of size $\delta$?

Comment: @Hwang  I think it is different, yes (it's formally easier; however, if you can convince me that the problems are equivalent that would be great)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, and the construction of the isotopy follows from rather elementary techniques:

- First, Hamiltonian isotopies act transitively on points in a connected symplectic manifold. In other words, we may assume that $g_1(0)=g_2(0)=p$.
- Second, after another Hamiltonian isotopy, we may even suppose that $D_0g_1=D_0g_2$ (consider e.g. paths of linear symplectomorphisms in a Darboux chart appropriately cut off by using Hamiltonians).
- Third, and finally, one can perform the "Alexander trick": a linear interpolation $g_i(tx)/t$, $t \in (0,1]$ where the (outer) scalar multiplication is defined *using some Darboux chart around $p \in X$*.

It can be checked that these two paths of symplectomorphisms are well-defined in some sufficiently small ball $B(\delta)$ and that both paths moreover extend to an isotopy from $g_i|_{B(\delta)}$ to the restriction of the linear symplectomorphism representing $D_0g_1=D_0g_2$ in that Darboux chart.